# Python List count() using a class and text file

Tags: python, list, class, count, ranking

I am a beginner at python and have a question.

I have 2 text files:

The first one contains a schedule for programs:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
Channel 1
16.00-17.45 Matinee: The kiss on the cross
17.45-17.50 The stock market today
------------------------------------------------------------------
Channel 2
8.30-9.00 The mosquito
9.00-10.00 Tip
17.50-18.20 In the company of dead masters
------------------------------------------------------------------
Channel 3
15.35-17.05 The weaker sex
17.05-18.00 The Onedine line
18.00-18.30 Children's trio: Dastardly & Mutley
```

I have created a class and managed on my own to create instances that look like this:

```
print(program_instances)

returns for example:
Channel 1, start:16.00 end:17.45 name:Matinee: The kiss on the cross 
Channel 1, start:17.45 end:17.50 name:The stock market today 
...
```

Then I have another text file with "viewer data":

```
File which contains data for one day collected from the TV sets included in the survey.
When the TV is switched on, it registers the time and tuned channel at fixed times every
day. Data from different devices is in the same file, but separated by dashed lines.

    Format: time/channel                
=================
19.37/2
19.52/2
21.07/1
21.22/1
21.37/1
-------
16.22/4
16.37/4
16.52/4
17.07/4
17.22/4
17.37/4
17.52/4
19.37/2
19.52/2
...
```

from this file, I want to calculate:

- How many times the TVs were switched on to that specific channel.
- The percentage of viewers from the total amount of data.
- The total amount of TV’s separated by dashed lines

ex. I want to be able to print a top 10 list:

```
--------------------- top 10 ------------------- 
1. program 1: 57 times (60%)
2. program 2: 47 times(49%)
3. program 3: 34 times (36%)
...

Data was collected from #number of TV’s
```

I'm having trouble deciding how to do when reading and calculating the second file.

Could I use a list in my class to add/ append a '*' symbol each time a channel has a viewer? Then use the count() function to count the number of occurrences of the symbol for each list?

ex:

```
viewers = ['*','*','*','*','*','*']
```

My class looks like this:

```
def __init__(self,channel,start, end, name, viewers, percentage):
        self.channel = channel
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.name = name
        self.viewers = viewers           #mabye use a list here?
        self.percentage = percentage
```

All help is much appreciated!

Comment: So using list works? What have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: Hello! @YevhenKuzmovych
I am unsure of how to add a list to the class. Do I add it inside the class or create a separate function? 

Also, I am unsure of how to count the occurrences in the text file. Each instance has a starting time and an end. Could I use an if, elif function to sort through the data? If that is possible, how do I do it?

Comment: These are multiple questions. Try researching each one of them. I'd suggest starting with some python basics tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a list that accepts that channel number for each time the channel is switched on(the list looks like:[1,2,1,1,4,4....] then use the list.count(the channel num) function to return the number of times for each channel. so you will create a function that returns the value from the list and does other calculations

Comment: Ok!@Tat but is there a way to also track how many TV:s the file contains at the same time?

Comment: you could convert that array into a dictionary and back to a list. original list=[1,2,4,4,4,2,1],final list=[1,2,4]. then count the final list to get number of Tv:s in the list

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).